# Does Cleanse work when you are silenced?

Tags: league-of-legends

I know Cleanse (the summoner spell) is supposed to get rid of stuns and everything, but since it's a spell itself, I was wondering if it also "cleansed" being hit with silence?

Answer (score 3):

> Removes all stuns, slows, taunts, fears, snares, silences, blinds and
>   immobilizers and lowers the duration of new ones applied by 65% for 3
>   seconds.

So it does in fact remove silence.
[Source](http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanse)

Comment: Well thank you. I thought I remembered reading somewhere that it was only stuns, slows, and snares.  I might have to start getting it now. :)

Comment: It is a strong spell especially if you are facing a team with a lot of CC effects.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Cleanse can be used to remove a Silence debuff on your champion.

In the past, Cleanse did not remove Silence effects. It wasn't until [patch 1.0.0.99](http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/showthread.php?t=218626) released on 08-23-2010 that Silence was added to the list of effects that cleanse would remove.

Answer (score 0):

According to the League of Legends Wikia http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Cleanse cleanse should work on silence.

Answer (score 0):

It does! Because... Well, let's face it, it would REALLY suck if it didn't. D:

Answer (score 0):

Yeap. Silence can be cleansed.

Answer (score 0):

Cleanse does work to get rid of silence. In addition to "    Removes all stuns, slows, taunts, fears, snares, silences, blinds and immobilizers and lowers the duration of new ones applied by 65% for 3 seconds."

It also gets rid of Ignite and other DPS spells.